# Windows application to monitor virtual memory activity

Tags: virtual-memory

Is there a windows application that shows a graphical representation of virtual memoey, along with which pages are resident, which are being moved in or out, and so on.

What I"m looking for is some information/entertainment when windows goes into one
of it's page thrashing death spirals, to show me whose pages are going in and out.

Answer (score 4):

[VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) is what you want.

Comment: You could also use Performance Monitor (part of Windows).

Comment: wow - published Mar 3 2010 - I guess some things are in the air.

Comment: Close but no cigar.  I'm thinking of something like the defragging
entertaimment, one dot per page or physical memory as the primary
display, with auxiliary information about which processes occupy it
and what the pages are doing recently.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe try windows Performance Monitor (under Administrative Tools). Right click in the graph area and select "Add Counters...". In the available counters area, select Process->Pool Paged Bytes. Then, in the list of processes, select <All instances>, and click the Add>> button. Once you've added the counters, you can right click in the graph again and select "Properties..." and go to the "Graph" tab to change the scale. I'm using Windows 7, so yours might be a little different.

Comment: Sorry but Process->Pool paged  bytes is very much NOT a process's chief contributor to the virtual address space it uses. The "pools" are just heaps in kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx.) for this? I am not running windows anymore so I can't test this program for you, but if you don't have this program installed anyway you should because it is the best process explorer I know(When I ran windows)

Answer (score 0):

There is no utility that does what you're asking for. The overhead would be far too high. You're talking about adding thousands of instructions to the processing for every page fault. This is why the VMmap and RAMmap sysinternals tools give static displays.

Under Windows Vista and later, you have Resource Monitor. Click the Memory tab. Click the column headings in the table to sort by "Working set", which is the physical memory in use by the process. Another good metric is "hard faults/sec". This is the number of page faults the process is incurring that must be resolved by reading from disk.

If these counters are not among the columns in the table, right-click on the column heading area, pick Select Columns, and turn them on.